# Laravel hasMany is Return No Results

Tags: php, sql, laravel

In Laravel, I am creating a message thread feature. My schema looks like this:

**MessageThreads Table**

| column |
| --- |
| id |

**MessageThreadParticapants Table**

| column |
| --- |
| thread_id |
| user_id |

And I have the corresponding models of **MessageThread** and  **MessageThreadParticapant**. In the **MessageThread** model, I have the following relation:

```
public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany(MessageThreadParticapant::class, 'thread_id', 'id');
}
```

Here is where things get funny. If I do:

```
MessageThread->users
```

I get an empty result. But if I do:

```
MessageThreadParticapant::where('thread_id', $same_thread_id)->get()
```

I get the correct amount of results back. What am I doing wrong here?

*UPDATE*

One of the suggestions was "hasMany(Model, 'foreign_key', 'local_key')" to be incorrect. Some more context,its failing my unit tests. I'm testing up a test as such:

```
public function testUsers() {

        $thread1 = MessageThread::factory()->create();

        $thread2 = MessageThread::factory()->create();

        $this->assertCount(0, $thread1->users);

        $this->assertCount(0, $thread2->users);

        $user1 = User::factory()->create();

        $user2 = User::factory()->create();

        $user3 = User::factory()->create();

        $user4 = User::factory()->create();

        MessageThreadParticapant::factory()->create([
            'user_id' => $user1->id,
            'thread_id' => $thread1->id
        ]);

        MessageThreadParticapant::factory()->create([
            'user_id' => $user2->id,
            'thread_id' => $thread1->id
        ]);

        MessageThreadParticapant::factory()->create([
            'user_id' => $user2->id,
            'thread_id' => $thread2->id
        ]);

        MessageThreadParticapant::factory()->create([
            'user_id' => $user3->id,
            'thread_id' => $thread2->id
        ]);

        MessageThreadParticapant::factory()->create([
            'user_id' => $user4->id,
            'thread_id' => $thread2->id
        ]);

        //PASSES!!!!
        $this->assertCount(2, MessageThreadParticapant::where('thread_id', $thread1->id)->get());
        //FAILS!!!
        $this->assertCount(2, $thread1->users);

        $this->assertCount(3, $thread2->users);
    }
```

At bottom of my test:

```
  //PASSES!!!!
        $this->assertCount(2, MessageThreadParticapant::where('thread_id', $thread1->id)->get());
        //FAILS!!!
        $this->assertCount(2, $thread1->users);
```

In other tests, $thread->users works correctly in getting the right amount of users back. Why are these getting different results?

Comment: @sta I updated the response above. It works in production, outside of testing, but only fails in testing.

Comment: check your table engine, seems like your test server db engine is InnoDB and your production table engine is MyISAM

Comment: Does you inverse works? for example a `messageThreads` relation inside `User` model.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in two steps.

1. Refresh

Lazy loading apparently only represents that state of the object at the time that it was loaded. Meaning it's not retrieving new data from the DB when the joined property is called. To solve, just do a refresh on the model and then access the joined property.

```
$model->refresh();
$model->users;
```

2. String ID

I'm using UUID in Postegresql. Even those I am using `$cast = ['id' => 'string'];` in model, this is not enough. I also have to add:

```
protected $keyType =  'string';
```